# How to use quicklisp when CL program is invoked as a shell script?

Tags: shell, automation, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I am currently have a small program in Common Lisp, which I want to run as a shell script. I am using the SBCL and perfectly fine with this so will prefer to stay on this platform. :)

I am aware about the `--script` option and it works flawlessly except for `(ql:quickload)` form.

My program uses the [CL-FAD](http://weitz.de/cl-fad/), which loads through `ql:quickload` (I think I should mention that it is package-loading function from [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/)). When script runs up to evaluating the

```
(ql:quickload :cl-fad)
```

form, it breaks with the next error:

```
package "QL" not found
```

Program is packed in the single source file, which has following header:

```
(defpackage :my-package
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:export :my-main-method))
```

It is simple automation executable, so I decided (maybe erroneously) not to write any ASDF system. It exports single function which should be run without any arguments.

For this program I am currently trying to write the launcher script, and this is what I am staring at:

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script
(load "my-program.lisp")
(in-package :my-package)
(my-main-method)
```

This three lines (not counting the shebang) is what I am want to automate. As I read in documentation, script with this shebang can be called as simple `./script.lisp`, and it really does this... with the error described before.

What I need to add in the launcher for `:cl-fad` to load properly? Documentation states that with `--script` option SBCL doesn't load any init file, so do I really need to copypaste the lines

```
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "systems/quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))
```

(which `ql:add-to-init-file` adds to .sbclrc), to my launcher script?
Maybe I have some deep architectural flaw in my program setup?

And yes, when I enter the lines which I try to automate in REPL in the sbcl itself, program runs as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a dedicated version of core image is a good option. You may:

1. load `quicklisp` and `sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die` in a new image. You write a shell/bat script named, say `qlsbcl`, like this:

   ```
   sbcl --core <my-new-image-full-path-location> "$@"
   ```
2. grab `clbuild2` at http://gitorious.org/clbuild2 and run `clbuild lisp`. You'll have to symlink clbuild to a binary directory in your path and tweak some scripts a bit if your `quicklisp` is not in the common place *~/quicklisp* (https://gist.github.com/1485836) or if you use `ASDF2` (https://gist.github.com/1621825). By doing so, `clbuild` create a new core with `quicklisp`, `ASDF` and anything you may add in *conf.lisp*. Now the shebang may look like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env sbcl --noinform --core <my-clbuild-install-directory>/sbcl-base.core --script
   ```

The advantage of `clbuild` is that you may easily create and manage core and quicklisp installation from shell for `sbcl` (by default) or any other modern CL like `ccl64` implementation. Mixing the two techniques (script and `clbuild`) will solve your problem.

Comment: I have quicklisp in the different dir and do not want _yet_ to hack other's scripts. :) Coredumping by first method worked great, I have many launchers in my `~/bin` already. And dumped image runs blazingly fast, too. %)

Comment: Yes! Working with images is great! That's why Smalltalkers begin their day-to-day work with a smile and Java Eclipse developers start their own with coffee.

Answer (score 19):

You are doing everything right.

Basically, before you can use `quicklisp`, you need to load it (currently, it's not bundled with SBCL, although it may change in the future). There are various ways to do it. For example, you can load your `.sbclrc` with the quicklisp init:

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script
(load ".sbclrc")
(load "my-program.lisp")
(in-package :my-package)
(my-main-method)
```

or just paste those lines in your script, like you have suggested.

Comment: Wow, "you are doing everything right"... this words are really rare find, thank you, @Vsevolod. Both yours and Martial answers are great and working, I felt sorry that one can mark only the single answer. :) I prefer coredumping though, it saves me one line in every script with little overhead of preparations in form of symlinking everything together.

Comment: @hijarian no problem. As I've said. there are numerous ways to solve your problem. I hope to see even more answers :)