# How to make Quicklisp available to a script that runs from a Shebang?

Tags: common-lisp, shebang, quicklisp

I've been playing around with Quicklisp lately, and have this minor problem working with scripts with Shebangs.

### Setup

I did the following:

1. Downloaded quicklisp with `curl https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp -o /tmp/quicklisp.lisp`
2. Installed it with `(quicklisp-quickstart:install)` while having `/tmp/quicklisp` loaded in the environment.
3. Added Quicklisp to init file using `(ql:add-to-init-file)`

### Problem

For a script that needs Quicklisp (specifically ASDF), I can run it with `sbcl --load ~/quicklisp/setup.lisp --script start.lisp` just fine. However, when I run it as a standalone script with the Shebang `/usr/bin/env sbcl --script`, it fails with an error saying that it isn't able to find things like `UIOP`, etc. unless I place the below two lines in the script itself:

```
(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")
(ql:quickload "asdf")
```

You can find my stupid experiment [here](https://github.com/myTerminal/forge/tree/13357749d76a6177da9142b9e38b875776093ea4), and the script in question [here](https://github.com/myTerminal/forge/blob/13357749d76a6177da9142b9e38b875776093ea4/start.lisp).

**PS:** Any pointers would be really helpful.

**PPS:** I'm sure it's a stupid mistake on my end, forgive me.

Comment: There's a very small limit on the number of arguments you can put in a shebang line. Like 2 or 3.

Comment: I thought I should mention [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229526/how-to-use-quicklisp-when-cl-program-is-invoked-as-a-shell-script?rq=1) here as it contains discussion on very similar lines.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need:

```
(require :asdf)
```

TBH, I don't know exactly why. `--script` equals to `--no-sysinit --no-userinit --disable-debugger --end-toplevel-options`, so it's a lot we ignore. (thus loading quicklisp's setup.lisp seems required too, because it won't be loaded by your .sbclrc, which is where Quicklisp adds this little snippet)

It's a setting I have needed in other environments, such as a CI.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `roswell` - which makes standalone scripts available which use Common Lisp code.

I described setting up `roswell` [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b). It is super easy.
I describe there system-wide installation of roswell or also how to locally install roswell in ubuntu, mac and windows.

Or you could also directly lookup on `roswell`'s [site](https://roswell.github.io/).

Using roswell would have the advantage that you can use any roswell-installable Common Lisp implementations, which are:

```
Candidates impls for installation are:
abcl-bin
allegro
ccl-bin
clasp-bin
clasp
clisp
cmu-bin
ecl
mkcl
sbcl-bin
sbcl
sbcl-source
```

not only `sbcl` alone.

And roswell allows scripts which are call-able directly from the shell while written in Common Lisp.

From inside roswell `$ ros ...` commands , quicklisp is available. So `$ ros install xxx` uses usually quicklisp to install `xxx`.

Using roswell, you can make any Common Lisp program callable from the bash by a single command - including your script - written in common lisp.

Look at e.g. here:
https://roswell.github.io/Roswell-as-a-Scripting-Environment.html

Comment: That's a lot of info. I'll check it out!